# How to connect to Oracle 9i through SSH tunnel if TNS protocol issues a REDIRECT to a random port?

Tags: oracle, connectivity, oracle-9i

Inspecting packets exchanged between `SQLDeveloper` and `Oracle 9i` I noticed that, in the beginning of the connection negotiation, the server issues a `REDIRECT` back to the client, pointing a port different from 1521. The client then connects using this new port. This is apparently a normal behavior of TNS protocol.
Because of this behavior it's difficult to connect remotely via SSH tunnel or through firewalls.

client sends this:

```
tns.connect_data = (DESCRIPTION=(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=xyz)(CID=(PROGRAM=SQL Developer)(HOST=__jdbc__)(USER=abc)))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.100.100)(PORT=1521)))
```

and receives this:

```
tns.redirect_data = (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.100.100)(PORT=1236))
```

Is there a way to disable this redirect? Or at least limit the redirection to a few known ports?

According to [this](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=port-range-in-tns) there are 2 solutions:

1. use shared server and configure the dispatchers
2. use connection manager

Regarding **1. shared servers**, I created a new shared server an tried to configure the dispatchers like [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/network.920/a96580/mts.htm#452761) and [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96540/statements_23a.htm#2053638):

```
alter system set DISPATCHERS='(PROTOCOL = TCP)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=myHost)(PORT=5000))' scope=spfile sid='xyz';
```

But I get errors like:

```
02065. 00000 -  "illegal option for ALTER SYSTEM" Cause: The option specified for ALTER SYSTEM is not supported
```

Removing the `scope` and `sid`:

```
00101. 00000 -  "invalid specification for system parameter DISPATCHERS" Cause: The syntax for the DISPATCHERS parameter is incorrect.
```

removing the `(PROTOCOL = TCP)`:

```
00105. 00000 -  "too many dispatcher configurations" Cause: Too many dispatcher configurations have been specified. No more can be added.
```

Regarding **2. connection manager** I enabled the `cman` and cman admin services, created `cman.ora` as:

```
cman = (ADDRESS_LIST=
           (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=myHost)(PORT=1630)(QUEUESIZE=32))
       )

cman_admin = (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=myHost)(PORT=1830))
```

and followed [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/network.920/a96580/cman.htm#485883). I always get connection refused. I could connect to port 1630, after putting it in the listener. In the end the port redirect still happened.

Comment: This is not behavior of any version of Oracle after 9i, specifically because it made connections through firewalls and such almost impossible. Why are you attempting to use an Oracle version that has been out of support for almost 20 years?

Comment: Reminder: 12g+ clients won't connect to 9i server period

Comment: @MichaelKutz I'm aware of that. I'm using an SQLDeveloper version that is compatible with Oracle 9i. I use it to connect to this Oracle on a daily basis.

Comment: @pmdba The Oracle version is out of my control. It will be used for a few more years. Do you know if shared server or connection manager can make it even slightly possible?

Comment: Technically you should be able to do it with either, but I think Connection Manager would have less of a potential impact on performance and not require you to open up any other ports. Connection Manager use requires an Enterprise Edition installation and license. I have a white paper here (https://pmdba.files.wordpress.com/2013/03/deploying-an-oracle-11gr2-connection-manager.pdf), written for CMan 11g, but should be mostly the same.

Comment: I would advise getting away from 9i as soon as possible; it's at least 20 versions behind current technology; I can't imagine that any OS that 9i runs on is supported anymore, either. The architecture isn't even remotely secure, and I suspect cannot be made so.